SWAGGER BUG: Only One Param Allowed (!SOLVED)
Got this option for my route, when acessing the first param (page) it returns properly the value typed in from swagger ui when it access the second param (genre), it literraly interprets it as a string '{genre}'. any thoughts, pls?
    app.get('/movies/:page/genres/:genre', (req,res) => {// route logic})

swagger options object
    '/movies/{page}/genres/{genre}': {
    get: {
    security: [{ 
    myAuth: []
    }],
    parameters: [
    {
    in: 'path',
    name: "page",
    required: true,
    type: "string",
    },
    {
    in: 'path',
    name: "genre",
    required: true,
    type: "string",
    },
    ],

I tried reading the swagger docs for getting the solution but it looks right to me.


when acessing the first param (page) it returns properly the value typed in from swagger ui when it access the second param (genre), it literraly interprets it as a string '{genre}'

It was a bug in Swagger UI v. 5.17.7 that was fixed in v. 5.17.8.

Neither one should work because you don't have schema defined for either parameter.
Try this...
parameters: [
    {
      in: 'path',
      name: "page",
      required: true,
       schema: {
        type: "string"
       },
    },
    {
      in: 'path',
      name: "genre",
      required: true,
      schema: {
        type: "string"
      },
    },
    ],


unfornatelly, still not working, as you can see in this image :/  : https://postimg.cc/vDcVsbVm

As you can see here, in the swagger ui, genre is not being replaced during the request:
https://postimg.cc/8Jm3T9np
